# custom message properties in scala play framework for removing hard coded string

Tags: java, scala, file-io, playframework, internationalization

this below code for getting keyword value from the text file works perfectly in **localhost**. but when i put this code in **AWS server**, it works sometimes only. sometimes it returns the `value for keyword` but mostly returns `null`

```
package models
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.util.Properties
import scala.language.postfixOps

object MsgModel {

  def getKeyword(msgKeyWord: String) = {
    var fileInput = new FileInputStream("./conf/keywords");
    val properties = new Properties
    properties.load(fileInput);

    var out = new FileOutputStream("./conf/keywords");
    properties.store(out, null);
    val Point = properties.getProperty(msgKeyWord)

    val key = properties.keySet()
    val data = Point
    fileInput.close();
    out.close();
    data
  }
}
```

some times

```
MsgModel.getkeyword("jid")//some times returns jid, which is expected
MsgModel.getkeyword("jid")//some times return null
```

file:**keywords.txt**

```
jid=jid
```

why it works sometimes only?

Comment: not get any solution, so i quit and now i am using http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/java/play/i18n/Messages.html and sure simple

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it as an issue of not having the file present in one of the underlying servers which AWS load balancer route your traffic to. Could you try to return the IP or some unique identifier of the system along with your result and notice if they are different in case of expected result and null value?

Comment: sorry i didn't understand `Could you try to return the IP or some unique identifier of the system along with your result`. what does it mean?

Comment: how i make sure that file is present underlying servers

Comment: I know this is on the server